# Why does my prompt in python appear before the output of the previous line?

Tags: python, prompt, interactive

I think this might have happened only after I started using zsh and prezto. (See screenshot)

[image: python-prompt-on-previous-line]

Here's the behaviour I was expecting:

```
>>> 4 + 5
9
>>>
```

How do I get the interactive python's behaviour back?

Comment: No idea - it's certainly odd.  But, since you suspect prezto, can you test by trying a different shell?

Comment: I tried using bash by typing `bash` at the command line and then `python`. I got the same thing. Then I thought maybe it's iTerm's problem and then I tried Terminal (on Yosemite) and got the same thing too.

Comment: I erased the ssd and installed el capitan today. Apple's python was ok, but macports' python gave me this behavior again. Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I found the solution from here! http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206795/using-python-screws-up-the-shell-and-or-terminal

Comment: Cool - for neatness' sake, why not add an answer to your own question and accept it.  That could help others even more than your comment.

Comment: stackoverflow thought it was a trivial answer and converted it to a comment